# How to delete gateway from default routing table use systemd

Tags: linux, systemd, routing

There are two physical interfaces on my machine, both with DHCP, so my default routing table looks like this:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.10.26.129    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp8s0
default         10.10.24.1      0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eno1
10.10.24.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
10.10.24.1      *               255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 eno1
```

In order to delete the `10.10.24.1` gateway, I run this:

```
route del default gw 10.10.24.1
```

I want it to be deleted after booting, `systemd` would be the suitable way, but how should I delete gateway from default routing table use systemd? Below is what I tried, but doesn't work.

```
[Unit]
Description=delete gateways from the main routing table

[Service]
Type=idle
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/route -b /etc/iproute2/delgw

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

file **delgw**:

```
del default gw 10.10.24.1
```

Comment: I think you've got the right idea, and are just missing syntax. My `route` doesn't accept a `-b` option, nor mention any option to read from a file. Try ignoring the `delgw` file and just calling `/bin/route del default gw 10.10.24.1` from the service file.

Comment: I think that it could be possible that when you execute the command to delete the entry, this entry is not in the table yet

Comment: @TomHunt Tried, still doesn't work, that `-b` is just to make the files organized.

Comment: @migrc After booting, I run `systemctl start myservice.service`, my routing table stays the same, but in this case, the entry is already in the entry.

Comment: Why don't you send the output of the command to a log file to see what is happening?